# Использование геттера для получения уже обработанных данных из базы

Tags: c#, json, .net

Всем привет.
 У меня есть класс, который соответствует модели схемы в базе.
Вот как он выглядит

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    [MsgPackArrayElement(0)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [MsgPackArrayElement(1)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [MsgPackArrayElement(2)]
    public string RegularExpression { get; set; }
}
```

RegularExpression это JSON в котором содержатся несколько значений.
Каждый раз мне нужно их сериализовать и десериализовать это значение для получения данных.

Изменить тип свойства я не могу, т.к. исходя из него генерируется array converter в сущности.
Можно ли через геттер как-либо получать уже десериализованный объект? Например такой:

```
public class JsonRegularExpression {
        public string Expression;
    }
```

Это объект, в которую я сейчас десериализую каждый раз эту строку.

Comment: Мне кажется ваша ошибка сейчас в том, что вы мешаете все в одну солянку. У вас должно быть для работы с базой - одно, для отображения и прочего - другое. Ну а так, если прям оч хочется все в одну кашу месить, то я бы сделал метод расширения и делал бы нечто такое: `var result = myServiceModel.GetExpression();`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял